# Fastest way to find the fewest calls of functions to get from one state to another state

Tags: python, algorithm

My problem is solveable in every programming language, nevertheless my examples will be in python and i would like most to get an answer including python code.

I have a state let's say for example:

```
state = {"underline":0, "bold":0, "color":0}
```

And i have "functions" They have to be able to set any key of the dict "state" to any constant integer. The functions could look like this:

```
functions = [{"color":0},                          # 0 color black
             {"color":1},                          # 1 color red
             {"color":2},                          # 2 color blue
             {"underline":1},                      # 3 underline
             {"bold":1},                           # 4 bold
             {"underline":0, "bold":0, "color":0}, # 5 reset all
             {"underlined":0, "bold":0}]           # 6 reset styles
```

I want to be able to apply the functions to the state. That could look like this:

```
state.update(functions[2])
state.update(functions[4])
```

My problem is, that i want to find the fewest function calls to get from one to another state. I want a function "get_functions" that returns the index (or the dict) of the functions i have to call in a list in the right oder, so that i call the fewest number of functions possible.

```
org = {"underline":1, "bold":0, "color":2}
dest = {"underline":0, "bold":1, "color":2}

calls = get_functions(org, dest, functions)

for i in calls:
  org.update(functions[i])
```

In this case the output of "get_functions" should be:

```
>>> get_functions(org, dest, functions)
[6, 4]
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I want to use this for string formatting with ANSI escape sequences. For reading a string with ANSI escape sequences i have a state variable where every formatting value is 0. I go over the text that i want to be formatted letter by letter and i save the current state with the current letter in a list. Everytime i hit a ANSI escape sequence i change the state. At the end i have a list with letters and every letter has its own state that includes its color and if its bold and so on.

Now i change this list with some functions to make it nice looking.

To generate a string from the list i go through the list and everytime something of the state changes i call "get_functions" with the arguments old state, new state and the dict. Then i write the output of "get_functions" to the string. Then i write the letter curent to the string too.

Comment: please post your initial implementation

Comment: This is essentially finding the shortest path in a directed graph.

Comment: Take a look at [backtracking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

Comment: @Smasho backtracking doesn't find the shortest path, it finds an arbitrary path.

Comment: So, as I see, the function set is: 1) set each property to a given number (passed as a parameter) (any, positive or nonzero?); 2) reset all properties to 0 - that's all?

Comment: How many functions there may be?

Comment: @JuanLopes about 80 functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is essentially [to find the shortest route in a directed unweighted graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Directed_unweighted_graphs). The algorithm to do it is the [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) ("wave method") or its faster but more complex alternative, "double wave method" (strangely, couldn't find an English source, maybe it's called differently there; your graph is rather small so you don't really need it).

So, you need to:

1. Build a representation of your graph of state transitions
2. Implement the search across it between you initial and goal states

Yet, with your stated set of transitions "set a single property to a given value", this basically degenerates to *"set all properties to dest values, one at a time, which are not already at it".*

If this is the case, I cannot see why this is even worth the trouble of asking a question.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach: his graph is implicit and unbounded. The functions are actually transformations in the data and can lead to  infinite graph nodes. In each step it will multiply the BFS queue by |functions|.

Comment: Well, only a few of the possible (infinite) state transitions are actually practical. So we can limit the graph with those.

Comment: In the example OP gave, yes, it is limited. But he also mentioned it can be any python function, imagine a function that sets "color" to a random value. It can be applied (virtually) infinite number of times. PS: it wasn't me who downvoted your answer.

Comment: Well, then he needs to narrow down the possible nature of those "functions".

Comment: Sorry my bad, the functions should be able to set any value to any specific integer.

Comment: @Tim By specific you mean a constant one? Do you think it is possible to have a function that sets a value to the same value of another key, for example?

Comment: @Juan Lopes No, just a constant number, from -∞ to ∞.

Answer (score -1):

What I believe you are trying to do can be as simple as the following code:

```
>>> state = {"underline":0, "bold":0, "color":0}
>>> new_state = {"underline":0, "bold":1, "color":2}
>>> state.update(new_state):
>>> state
{'bold': 1, 'color': 2, 'underline': 0}
```

Please note that my example even works if `state` and `new_state` have different keys, e.g.:

```
>>> state = {"bold":0, "color":0}
>>> new_state = {"underline":0, "bold":1, "color":2}
>>> state.update(new_state)
>>> state
{'bold': 1, 'color': 2, 'underline': 0}
```

Why do you need `get_function` if you already know what your new states will be? You pass `dest` into `get_function`!

In response to your EDIT, and the person who down voted my answer, maybe you'll enjoy reading my article [How to build SQL Queries the Rube Goldberg Way](https://denhartog.com/article/2015/01/29/how-build-sql-queries-rube-goldberg-way/). I cannot imagine you need a complex algorithm to change the styling of letters.

Comment: Perhaps there's something missing from the example and @Tim has to call some named functions, represented by the `functions` list, to do the actual update?

Comment: @markw is right. Read the EDIT at the end of my question.

Comment: I downvoted this answer. OP's question didn't asked for the best pythonic way to update a dict. I don't usually downvote answers that provide a true effort to answer the question, even if it is not the best answer (It wasn't me who downvote @ivan_pozdeev's answer), but your answer assumes the OP's reasons to ask so aren't important.

Comment: @Juan, Read the first sentence of my response. Then read the question I ask right after my code blocks. Then enjoy [Difference Between Men and Women Shopping](http://bit.ly/1DCbM85). Then have a wonderful rest of your day.